# Establishing Relation between two columns of mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

Guys I have a mysql table in which I have three columns.

(1) Latitude

(2) Longitude

(3)Alternate_Longitude

From my jdbc code I am passing Latitude and Longitude only but my requirement is that the "Alternate_Longitude" column should automatically gets populated such that

Alternate_Longitude = Longitude + 0.1;

I tried searching for "alter table" command so that I can make such relationship between the two columns but I am not getting any. Can anyone tell me please if it is possible or not? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the feature you are looking for is a trigger which you attach to your table.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON my_table_name
     FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
        SET new.Alternate_Longitude = new.Longitude + 0.1;
     END;//
delimiter ;
```

The above SQL will create trigger which will automatically perform the addition everytime a new record is inserted into the database. Within a trigger the "new" keyword refers to a special internal table with the same column names as the table that the trigger is attached to.